# completing an Identity matrix using only row addition

Tags: linear-algebra

Given an Identity Matrix and Row Addition, what is the minimum number of Row Addition Operations necessary to fill the matrix (have every entry be non-zero)?

Comment: adding row 1 to row 2, row 2 to row 3.... row n-1 to row n (resulting in n-1 row additions). Then going back and adding row n back to the rest of the matrix resulting in another n-1 row additions for a total of 2n-2. We want to show that this is minimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as you explained in your comment you did the following:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&1\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}\rightarrow
\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&1&1\\1&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

For a total of $2(n-1)$ additions, and you'd like to show that this is minimal.

First note to get one row complete, you need at least $n-1$ additions, since every site will have to be added once.
We then get something of the following form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\0&1&0\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Since this is the minimum to get a single row, we'll now be adding this row to every *other* row, to get the minimum of the entire matrix, so we need to do another $n-1$ additions for a total of $2(n-1)$ additions. We end up with:
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&2&1\\1&1&2\end{bmatrix}$$

If you were to be able to do it in fewer, you either couldn't complete a full row, or a row would be missing.

Comment: Thanks so much! if I may ask a slight variation of this problem that is a bit trickier, suppose you have a Row Addition Operator RAO(k,j) that adds row k to row j, and simultaneously adds row row j to row k. how many such operations of this type are needed to fill the matrix?

Comment: It's really not that much trickier. It helps to draw them out in these cases. Note how you still need at least $n$ operators to get one row complete. The key is, that you're now able to complete the top $2$ rows *at once*! This is great, because this saves you a step (only $n-2$ rows left with $0$'s in them). So you end up with $2n-3$ for a minimum.

Comment: Thats what I initially though but consider the counter example where A is a 4x4 matrix. I could apply the operator, RAO(1,2), RAO(3,4), RAO(1,3), RAO(2,4). this is 4 instances of the application of the operator, which is one less than your prediction.

Comment: @Yonahshmalo Oh man, this is much tougher.. For $n=2^i$, it is clear: it takes $n$ operations. But I run in a brick wall beyond that, sorry..

Comment: wait, how can you do 8x8 in only 8 applications?

Comment: Lol turns out my brain melted after an hour of working the problem :P Meant to say that for $n = 2^i$ you can do it in $^2\log(n)(\frac{n}{2})$ operations. Which follows the sequence (matrices of powers of 2): $0,1,4, 12, 32, 80,...$  But that equation breaks down at 3. So I tried ceiling and floor functions on the log, getting no results. But while writing this comment I'm thinking that $\lceil(\log_2(n)(\frac{n}{2}))\rceil$ might work. So verifying through Wolfram alpha, it works for $n= 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8$. I didn't manually check 7, so I can't know that one for sure.

Comment: you managed to do 6 in log(6)(3)? can you show me the steps? Sorry if this is taking up all of your time lol.

Comment: No worries, I really enjoy this problem :) Note that $\lceil \log_2(6)(\frac{6}2)\rceil = 8$. My solution in 8 steps is: (1,2), (5,6), (2,3), (4,5), (2,5), (3,4), + the last 2 to finish it (1,2), (4,5) works. This is 4 steps of 2 so 8 steps total.

Comment: ok I tried your argument for 8 and it does seem to work as I cant find a way to do it in less than 12. however your equation implies that a 32x32 matrix could be done in 80, but I think I could do it in 60.

Comment: Show me the way :) (linking a picture is probably best)

Comment: instead of making a 32X32 matrix ill just tell you how to do it. (1,2), (2,3)...(29,30), (31,32), (30,31), (29,32), (32,1), (32,2), (32,3)...(32,29)

Comment: Oh, yeah. You can even do it in 59. So the function I'd say is most likely so far would be $\min\{\lceil\log_2(n)\frac{n}{2}\rceil,\;2n-3\}$. No idea if that's most efficient but it's one way :P

Comment: Sorry I went on vacation and I promised myself not to think about this question until I was done lol. I have a follow up that might prove even more difficult to show. can we show that under minimal completion, there is a row k such that there was an instance where (k,j) did not decrease the number of 0s in its row. i.e. was there a row that was added to another where any non-zero element in the other, was also non-zero in it?

Answer (score 1):

You need **n-1 addition** for the first row (you add the others to the first) and **1 addition** for the others n-1 (you add the first to the others).